# Calendario con datetimepicker deshabilitando horas

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Necesito crear un calendario (Datetimepicker o jquery-simpe, he probado muchas cosas y no he podido) con un input para la fecha y otro para la hora, de la siguiente forma:

> Cuando sea los lunes tiene que tener un rango de horas entre 16:00 a 20:00 con 30 minutos de diferencia.
> De martes a viernes normal de 10:00 a 14:00 y 16:00 a 20:00 y los sábados de 16:00 a 20:00.

La cosa sería que cuando se seleccione una fecha y una hora se guarde en la base de datos y esa hora se deshabilite o se quite ya que estaría reservada.

```js
$(function () {
$("#fecha").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
        onSelect: function(dia_semm) {                         
      
        alert(dia_semm);
       
        },
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: end_day,
        //  beforeShowDay: my_check,
        beforeShowDay: my_check
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Pues si has intentado muchas cosas, adjunta el código de lo que has intentado

Comment: Perdonar que no he podido antes escribir el codigo

Comment: No puedo meter el codigo como lo hago es que soy nuevo

Comment: Ya lo he modificado pero ya lo que necesito es como sacar el día de la semana del día seleccionado  ya que si pulso hoy me sale 21/06/2022 y necesito saber el dia de la semana para hacerle yo un array dependiendo del día de la semana

Comment: El tema es Mint Choc , La version es esa , 1.13.1(Stable, for jQuery1.8+), https://jqueryui.com/download/, eso es lo que pides?

Comment: Es que llevo ya un par de meses con un curso y ahora mientras que hago el curso estoy haciendo una pagina web y la verdad que me esta gustando he creado sesiones con php y demas y la putada es que el datepicker me da muchos problemas  y la verdad que me estoy agobiando mucho, porque con el input type ="date" si puedo sacar el dia de la semana pero tengo que hacerlo con datepicker que controlo mas los dias para deshabilitarlos etcc.  POSDATA NO ES UNA TAREA NI NADA DE ESO ES PARA UNA WEB REAL QUE VOY HACER CUANDO LA TENGA TERMINADA SI ESO LA PONGO POR AQUI SI SE PUEDE

Comment: No, no se puede hacer propaganda de webs propias.  He votado para que se reabra la pregunta, la solución pasa por cambiar esto: `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',` a esto: `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`, (con dos yy para que coja bien el año, sino después se cree que es 1922), y luego convertir tu formato de fecha a un formato aceptado por date() de javascript, y finalmente usar la función `getDay()` para obtener el número de dia de la semana. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/x3cjya85/

Comment: Vale haber si se puede abrir la pregunta. Mañana lo miraré porque hoy llevo todo el día. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No podía esperar mas y al final lo estado probando y funcionaba gracias no... Muchisiiimmasssssss graciass maquinaaaaa :) estaba ya como loco no sabia que hacer, lo que he cambiado en vez de que me de el nombre que me de el numero de la semana perfectoo enserio muchsiimas gracias eres un grande

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Ojo con el número de la semana, pues el domingo es el 0, el lunes el 1, etc...  No se si reabriran la pregunta porque pides más cosas y no se ve el intento, pero bueno, si con lo que tienes puedes seguir perfecto, y sino deberás reescribirla de nuevo con más datos o abrir una nueva partiendo de lo que acabas de aprender.

Comment: Si si lo sé que el 0 es domingo vamos perfecto si lo hubiera sabido antes hubiera escrito he mirado por todos los lados y no me atrevía a escribir. No no si era esto lo que necesitaba para saber el día de la semana los lunes y sábado para meterle un array de horas distintas ya que del martes al viernes es igual el horario. Perfecto todo muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: masterguru haber si me puedes ayudar a una pregunta que hecho si te metes en mi perfil creo que puedes verla no?? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/542305/no-puedo-recorrer-el-foreach-dentro-de-jquery-usando-php-pero-si-se-me-conecta-a

Comment: Dos cosas: Los comentarios no se usan como chat. Y por favor pongan la solución como respuesta. Nadie va a saber cómo resolver ésto si lo dejan en los comentarios :)

Comment: @Alfabravo: Hecho! No podia poner la respuesta antes porque ya estaba cerrada cuando lo supe solucionar y de ahí el "chat". Gracias por reabrir la pregunta! :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Gracias a @Alfabravo por reabrir la pregunta para poder mostrar esta respuesta)

La solución pasa por cambiar esto:

```javascript
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y'
```

a esto:

```javascript
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```

con dos `yy` para que coja bien el año, sino después se cree que es 1922), y luego convertir tu formato de fecha a un formato aceptado por [date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) de javascript:

```javascript
const [day, month, year] = dia_semm.split('/')
const date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day)
```

y finalmente usar la función [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) para obtener el número de dia de la semana:

```javascript
const num_dia_sem = date.getDay();
```

Aquí dejo un snippet con todo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fecha").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dia_semm) {
      const [day, month, year] = dia_semm.split('/');
      const date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day)
      const num_dia_sem = date.getDay();
      console.log(num_dia_sem)
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-hlKLmzaRlE8SCJC1Kw8zoUbU8BxA+8kR3gseuKfMjxA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="fecha">
```