# No puedo recorrer el foreach dentro de jquery usando php pero si se me conecta a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Buenas tengo el problema que no me funciona cuando llega a

```
$reservas=[];
foreach($horas as $hora){
   array_push($reservas,$hora["hora"]);
}
print_r($reservas);
```

pero si lo saco afuera del datepicker si me funciona pero necesito meterlo dentro ya que tengo que comparar las horas que estan guardas en la base de datos para que cuando seleccione el dia deshabilitar las horas guardadas en la base de datos.
Necesito ejecutar ese foreach dentro del jquery para comprobar las horas de la semana...
Que podria hacer para que me lo ejecute es que necesito primero saber las horas guardadas de la base de datos para comprobar despues los dias de la semana si es uno tiene unas horas,

```
$(function() {

const dias_semana = {
  0: 0,
1: 1,
2: 2,
3: 3,
4: 4,
5: 5,
6: 6
}
$("#fecha").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dia_semm) {
      const [day, month, year] = dia_semm.split('/');
      const date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day);
      const num_dia_sem = date.getDay();
    //   alert(dia_semm);


    <?php
     $consultahora = "SELECT date_format(hora,'%H:%i') as 'hora' from reservas where fechareserva='$fechacliente' and idpeluqueros=1;";
     $resultado1 = $conexion->prepare($consultahora);
     $resultado1->execute();
     $horas=$resultado1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $reservas=[];
      foreach($horas as $hora){
                 
       array_push($reservas,$hora["hora"]);
                 
                }
                         
       print_r($reservas); 
                        
    ?>


      if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==1){
        var dia= new Array();
        var barra_horas = '';
        dia=horaslune();
        var long = dia.length;
        // alert(long);
        for(i=0;i<long;i++)
        {   
             barra_horas = barra_horas+dia[i] ;
        }
        document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;
      }
      if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==6){
        var dias= new Array();
        var barra_horas = '';
        dias=horassabad();
        var long = dias.length;
        // alert(long);
        for(i=0;i<long;i++)
        {   
             barra_horas = barra_horas+dias[i] ;
        }
        document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;

      }
      if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==2 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==3 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==4 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==5 ){
        var diass= new Array();
        var barra_horas = '';
        diass=horas();
        var long = diass.length;
        // alert(long);
        for(i=0;i<long;i++)
        {   
             barra_horas = barra_horas+diass[i] ;
        }
        document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;
      } 
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
           minDate: today,
           maxDate: end_day,
    //  beforeShowDay: my_check,
           beforeShowDay: my_check

  });
});
```

Comment: Jesus, en realidad cuando se ha cargado la página el navegador ejecuta ese código que tienes ahí, y por el medio (se entiende que Javascript) se encuentra el resultado originado por el pho, que es el resultado de impresión de una variable (`$reservas`), pero no afecta al `OnSelect`. Si quieres ver el resultado, fíjate en el código fuente del navegador en esa zona, después de `//   alert(dia_semm);` Además, no se sabe lo que es `$fechacliente` porque lo utilizas pero no está declarado o asignado en ningún sitio

Comment: Estoy consultando y ahora si me lo recoge conviertiendo            
 $horasJS = json_encode($reservas);
  echo "var horasReservadas= ".$horasJS;                                           Pero ahora me falta por lo que se  ve utilizar ajax para refrescar la consulta y hay me pierdo

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos rapidas opciones: Al cargar la pagina ejecuta tu funcion y guardala en una variable global de JS. (Analiza la situacion de que la query no retorne nada)

```
let horasDb = JSON.parse(`<?php echo json_encode($reservas); ?>`);
```

Luego en tu codigo js el codigo que tienes para generar el datepicker englobalo en una funcion y llamalo una vez esté cargada la web:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    iniciarDatePicker()
}
```

La otra opcion es trar la data mediante una peticion AJAX y luego generar el datepicker.

Comment: Como seria la otra opcion del data con AJAX es que estoy perdido en ajax la verdad y estoy un poco liado porque llevo poco tiempo programando perdona y gracias